# OpenLDAP how to ensure uniqueness of the mail field within two subtrees while allowing duplicates across the subtrees?

Tags: email, ldap, openldap, postfix-mta

I am using OpenLDAP and I store my users under `ou=users,ou=developers,o=orga,dc=domain,dc=com`

Each user have a `mail` attribute which is used by application that use the LDAP for authentication.

I also have a postfix mail server that I configured for using ldap. I store my email under `dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com`

[image]

I am now not able to set the real email in my user because the cn of the email is unique.

```
Attribute value would not be unique
This update has been or will be cancelled, it would result in an attribute value not being unique. You might like to search the LDAP server for the offending entry.
```

I am storing the email dn instead but now I have the wrong email loaded and visible in most of my application like Gitlab :

`Email: mail=me@domain.com,dc=mailaccount,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com`

I was thinking it was OK to store the mail server account and the users in a differents part of my ldap.

I can only import `*.ldif` file in phpLDAPadmin to edit entries and configuration, I don't the synthax for this.

**edit**

This is my postfix configuration:

## ldap-aliases.cf

```
server_host = ldap://virtual.domain.com
server_port = 389
search_base = dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
query_filter = (&(objectClass=CourierMailAlias) (mail=%s))
result_attribute = maildrop
bind = yes
bind_dn = cn=readonly,dc=domain,dc=com
bind_pw = 123
version = 3

tls_ca_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
tls_cert = /etc/postfix/ssl/mail.domain.com-full.pem
tls_key = /etc/postfix/ssl/mail.domain.com-key.pem
```

## ldap-accounts.cf

```
server_host = ldap://virtual.domain.com
server_port = 389
search_base = dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
query_filter = (&(objectClass=CourierMailAccount)(mail=%s))
result_attribute = mailbox
bind = yes
bind_dn = cn=readonly,dc=domain,dc=com
bind_pw = 123
version = 3

tls_ca_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
tls_cert = /etc/postfix/ssl/mail.domain.com-full.pem
tls_key = /etc/postfix/ssl/mail.domain.com-key.pem
```

## ldap-domain.cf

```
server_host = ldap://virtual.domain.com
server_port = 389
search_base = dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
query_filter = (&(description=virtualDomain)(dc=%s))
result_attribute = dc
bind = yes
bind_dn = cn=readonly,dc=domain,dc=com
bind_pw = 123
version = 3

tls_ca_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
tls_cert = /etc/postfix/ssl/mail.domain.com-full.pem
tls_key = /etc/postfix/ssl/mail.domain.com-key.pem
```

This is the export of the whole tree

## LDIF Export for dc=domain,dc=com

```
# Server: ldap.service.domain-ovh.consul (ldap.service.domain-ovh.consul)
# Search Scope: sub
# Search Filter: (objectClass=*)
# Total Entries: 74
#
# Generated by phpLDAPadmin (http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net) on June 14, 2017 9:48 pm
# Version: 1.2.3

version: 1

# Entry 1: dc=domain,dc=com
dn: dc=domain,dc=com
dc: domain
o: vdm Ltd
objectclass: top
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization

# Entry 2: cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator
objectclass: simpleSecurityObject
objectclass: organizationalRole
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789

# Entry 3: cn=readonly,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: cn=readonly,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: readonly
description: LDAP read only user
objectclass: simpleSecurityObject
objectclass: organizationalRole
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789

# Entry 4: cn=readonlypw,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: cn=readonlypw,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: readonlypw
description: LDAP read only user with password
objectclass: simpleSecurityObject
objectclass: organizationalRole
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789

# Entry 5: dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
dc: mail
o: mail
objectclass: top
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization

# Entry 6: dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
dc: domain.com
description: virtualDomain
o: domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789

# Entry 7: dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
dc: mailAccount
o: mailAccount
objectclass: top
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization

# Entry 8: mail=Tom.Joseph@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain...
dn: mail=Tom.Joseph@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=ma
 il,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: Tom.Joseph@domain.com
displayname: Tom Joseph
givenname: Tom
homedirectory: /var/mail
mail: Tom.Joseph@domain.com
mailbox: domain.com/Tom.Joseph/
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAccount
sn: Joseph
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789

# Entry 9: mail=tom.soyer@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain...
dn: mail=tom.soyer@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=
 mail,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: tom.soyer@domain.com
displayname: tom.soyer
givenname: Tom
homedirectory: /var/mail
mail: tom.soyer@domain.com
mailbox: domain.com/tom.soyer/
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAccount
sn: Soyer
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789

# Entry 10: mail=john.woe@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain...
dn: mail=john.woe@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=
 mail,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: john.woe@domain.com
displayname: john.woe
givenname: Mat
homedirectory: /var/mail
mail: john.woe@domain.com
mailbox: domain.com/john.woe/
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAccount
sn: Voltaire
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789

# Entry 11: mail=git@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=m...
dn: mail=git@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=kopa
 xgroup,dc=com
cn: git@domain.com
displayname: gitlab
givenname: gitlab
homedirectory: /var/mail
mail: git@domain.com
mailbox: domain.com/git/
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAccount
sn: Email
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789+DowTdRhEhkqVAwASugKp

# Entry 12: mail=no-reply@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com...
dn: mail=no-reply@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc
 =domain,dc=com
cn: no-reply@domain.com
displayname: no-reply
givenname: no-reply
homedirectory: /var/mail
mail: no-reply@domain.com
mailbox: domain.com/no-reply/
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAccount
sn: no-reply
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789

# Entry 13: mail=relay@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc...
dn: mail=relay@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=ko
 paxgroup,dc=com
cn: relay@domain.com
displayname: relay
givenname: relay
homedirectory: /var/mail
mail: relay@domain.com
mailbox: domain.com/relay/
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAccount
sn: relay
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789

# Entry 14: mail=test@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=...
dn: mail=test@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=kop
 axgroup,dc=com
cn: test@domain.com
displayname: Dev Email
givenname: Dev
homedirectory: /var/mail
mail: test@domain.com
mailbox: domain.com/test/
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAccount
sn: Email
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789

# Entry 15: dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
dc: mailAlias
o: mailAlias
objectclass: top
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization

# Entry 16: mail=accounting@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com...
dn: mail=accounting@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc
 =domain,dc=com
cn: accounting@domain.com
displayname: Everybody
mail: accounting@domain.com
maildrop: sbg@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: accounting

# Entry 17: mail=vdm@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mai...
dn: mail=vdm@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=vdmg
 roup,dc=com
cn: vdm@domain.com
displayname: Tom Joseph
givenname: Tom
mail: vdm@domain.com
maildrop: Tom.Joseph@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Joseph

# Entry 18: mail=tsr@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mai...
dn: mail=tsr@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=vdmg
 roup,dc=com
cn: tsr@domain.com
displayname: tom.soyer
givenname: Sofiane
mail: tsr@domain.com
maildrop: tom.soyer@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Soyer

# Entry 19: mail=all@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mai...
dn: mail=all@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=vdmg
 roup,dc=com
cn: all@domain.com
displayname: Everybody
mail: all@domain.com
maildrop: sbg@domain.com tsr@domain.com vdm@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Everybody

# Entry 20: mail=board@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=m...
dn: mail=board@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=kopa
 xgroup,dc=com
cn: board@domain.com
displayname: Board
mail: board@domain.com
maildrop: sbg@domain.com tsr@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Board

# Entry 21: mail=dev@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mai...
dn: mail=dev@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=vdmg
 roup,dc=com
cn: dev@domain.com
displayname: Developers
mail: dev@domain.com
maildrop: sbg@domain.com tsr@domain.com vdm@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Developers

# Entry 22: mail=sbg@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mai...
dn: mail=sbg@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=vdmg
 roup,dc=com
cn: sbg@domain.com
displayname: john.woe
givenname: Mat
mail: sbg@domain.com
maildrop: john.woe@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Voltaire

# Entry 23: mail=hongkong@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,d...
dn: mail=hongkong@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=k
 opaxgroup,dc=com
cn: hongkong@domain.com
displayname: Hong-Kong Offices
mail: hongkong@domain.com
maildrop: sbg@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Hong-Kong Offices

# Entry 24: mail=job@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mai...
dn: mail=job@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=vdmg
 roup,dc=com
cn: job@domain.com
displayname: Jobs
mail: job@domain.com
maildrop: sbg@domain.com vdm@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Jobs

# Entry 25: mail=media@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=m...
dn: mail=media@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=kopa
 xgroup,dc=com
cn: media@domain.com
displayname: Jobs
mail: media@domain.com
maildrop: sbg@domain.com vdm@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Jobs

# Entry 26: mail=postmaster@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com...
dn: mail=postmaster@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc
 =domain,dc=com
cn: postmaster@domain.com
displayname: postmaster
mail: postmaster@domain.com
maildrop: sbg@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: postmaster

# Entry 27: mail=social@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=...
dn: mail=social@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=kop
 axgroup,dc=com
cn: social@domain.com
displayname: Social
mail: social@domain.com
maildrop: sbg@domain.com vdm@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Social

# Entry 28: mail=test1@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=m...
dn: mail=test1@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=kopa
 xgroup,dc=com
cn: test1@domain.com
displayname: Test Email
mail: test1@domain.com
maildrop: test@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Test Email

# Entry 29: mail=test2@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=m...
dn: mail=test2@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=kopa
 xgroup,dc=com
cn: test2@domain.com
displayname: Test Email
mail: test2@domain.com
maildrop: test@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Test Email

# Entry 30: mail=test3@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=m...
dn: mail=test3@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=kopa
 xgroup,dc=com
cn: test3@domain.com
displayname: Test Email
mail: test3@domain.com
maildrop: test@domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Test Email

# Entry 31: mail=vietnamese@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com...
dn: mail=vietnamese@domain.com,dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc
 =domain,dc=com
cn: vietnamese@domain.com
displayname: Social
mail: vietnamese@domain.com
maildrop: sbg@domain.com vdm@domain.com tsr@domain.com debbiemcl
 ean86@gmail.com d.Voltaire@gmail.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: CourierMailAlias
sn: Social

# Entry 32: o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
o: vdm Ltd
o: vdm
objectclass: top
objectclass: organization

# Entry 33: ou=administrations,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: ou=administrations,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: administrations

# Entry 34: ou=groups,ou=administrations,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: ou=groups,ou=administrations,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

# Entry 35: cn=odoo_users,ou=groups,ou=administrations,o=vdm,dc=domain...
dn: cn=odoo_users,ou=groups,ou=administrations,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: odoo_users
description: Users allowed to login to odoo.domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om

# Entry 36: ou=users,ou=administrations,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: ou=users,ou=administrations,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: users

# Entry 37: ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: developers

# Entry 38: ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

# Entry 39: cn=git_users,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc...
dn: cn=git_users,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: Git Users
cn: git_users
description: Users allowed to login to git.domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
uniquemember: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 40: cn=jenkins_admins,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domaino...
dn: cn=jenkins_admins,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: Jenkins Administrators
cn: jenkins_admins
description: Staff members allowed to administrate to jenkins build system
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om

# Entry 41: cn=jenkins_users,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domainou...
dn: cn=jenkins_users,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: Jenkins Users
cn: jenkins_users
description: Staff members allowed to login to jenkins build system
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om

# Entry 42: cn=private_users,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domainou...
dn: cn=private_users,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: Private git users
cn: private_users
description: Users allowed to login to the private git
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om

# Entry 43: ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com...
dn: ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: sonar

# Entry 44: cn=api-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=kopa...
dn: cn=api-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=vdmg
 roup,dc=com
cn: api-administrators
description: administrators of domain/api
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om

# Entry 45: cn=api-developers,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc...
dn: cn=api-developers,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain
 ,dc=com
cn: api-developers
description: developers of domain/api
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
uniquemember: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 46: cn=backoffice-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers...
dn: cn=backoffice-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc
 =domain,dc=com
cn: backoffice-administrators
description: administrators of domain/backoffice
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om

# Entry 47: cn=backoffice-developers,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=k...
dn: cn=backoffice-developers,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=kop
 axgroup,dc=com
cn: backoffice-developers
description: developers of domain/backoffice
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
uniquemember: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 48: cn=bootstrap-styled-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=deve...
dn: cn=bootstrap-styled-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=ko
 pax,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: bootstrap-styled-administrators
description: administrators of bootstrap-styled
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 49: cn=bootstrap-styled-developers,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=develope...
dn: cn=bootstrap-styled-developers,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,
 dc=domain,dc=com
cn: bootstrap-styled-developers
description: developers of bootstrap-styled
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
uniquemember: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 50: cn=dev-tools-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,...
dn: cn=dev-tools-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=
 domain,dc=com
cn: dev-tools-administrators
description: administrators of module/devtools/*
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om

# Entry 51: cn=dev-tools-developers,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=ko...
dn: cn=dev-tools-developers,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=kopa
 xgroup,dc=com
cn: dev-tools-developers
description: developers of module/devtools/*
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
uniquemember: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 52: cn=java-api-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o...
dn: cn=java-api-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=k
 opaxgroup,dc=com
cn: java-api-administrators
description: administrators of git/java-api/*
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om

# Entry 53: cn=java-api-developers,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=kop...
dn: cn=java-api-developers,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=vdm
 group,dc=com
cn: java-api-developers
description: developers of git/java-api/*
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
uniquemember: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 54: cn=quality-gates-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=develop...
dn: cn=quality-gates-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm
 ,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: quality-gates-administrators
description: quality-gates administrators
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 55: cn=quality-profiles-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=deve...
dn: cn=quality-profiles-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=ko
 pax,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: quality-profiles-administrators
description: quality-profiles administrators
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 56: cn=redstar-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=...
dn: cn=redstar-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=ko
 paxgroup,dc=com
cn: redstar-administrators
description: administrators of redstar/*
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 57: cn=redstar-developers,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=kopa...
dn: cn=redstar-developers,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=vdmg
 roup,dc=com
cn: redstar-developers
description: developers of redstar/*
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
uniquemember: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 58: cn=sonar-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=ko...
dn: cn=sonar-administrators,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=kopa
 xgroup,dc=com
cn: sonar-administrators
description: Administrators of https://sonarqube.domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om

# Entry 59: cn=sonar-users,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=ko...
dn: cn=sonar-users,ou=sonar,ou=groups,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc
 =com
cn: sonar-users
description: Users of https://sonarqube.domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 60: ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: users

# Entry 61: c=FR,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: c=FR,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
c: FR
description: France officies
objectclass: country
objectclass: top

# Entry 62: c=HK,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: c=HK,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
c: HK
description: Hong-Kong officies
objectclass: country
objectclass: top

# Entry 63: c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
c: VN
description: Vietnam officies
objectclass: country
objectclass: top

# Entry 64: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=...
dn: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: john.woe
employeetype: developer
gecos: john.woe
gidnumber: 14564101
givenname: Mat
homedirectory: /home/sbg
loginshell: /bin/bash
mail: mail=john.woe@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,d
 c=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: posixAccount
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
sn: Voltaire
uid: sbg
uidnumber: 14583102
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789

# Entry 65: ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: school

# Entry 66: ou=groups,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: ou=groups,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

# Entry 67: cn=module_users,ou=groups,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=...
dn: cn=module_users,ou=groups,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: School git users
cn: module_users
description: Users allowed to login to module.domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
uniquemember: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 68: cn=school_users,ou=groups,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=...
dn: cn=school_users,ou=groups,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: School git users
cn: school_users
description: Users allowed to login to school.domain.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniquemember: uid=sbg,c=VN,ou=users,ou=developers,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=c
 om
uniquemember: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
uniquemember: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com

# Entry 69: ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: users

# Entry 70: c=FR,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: c=FR,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
c: FR
description: France officies
objectclass: country
objectclass: top

# Entry 71: c=HK,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: c=HK,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
c: HK
description: Hong-Kong officies
objectclass: country
objectclass: top

# Entry 72: c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
c: VN
description: Vietnam officies
objectclass: country
objectclass: top

# Entry 73: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: uid=vdm,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: Tom Joseph
employeetype: developer
gecos: Tom Joseph
gidnumber: 14564103
givenname: Tom
homedirectory: /home/vdm
loginshell: /bin/bash
mail: mail=Tom.Joseph@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=
 mail,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: posixAccount
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
sn: Joseph
uid: vdm
uidnumber: 14583104
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789+eiWwf9KTr4A+79CjyqY5/okZsL2Ke1

# Entry 74: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
dn: uid=tsr,c=VN,ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: tom.soyer
employeetype: developer
gecos: tom.soyer
gidnumber: 14564103
homedirectory: /home/tsr
loginshell: /bin/bash
mail: mail=tom.soyer@domain.com,dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,d
 c=mail,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: posixAccount
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
sn: Soyer
uid: tsr
uidnumber: 14583104
userpassword: {SSHA}123456789123456789123456789
```

Comment: How does the `cn` of the mail entry being unique prevent you from storing the email address in the `mail` entry of a user? There is no uniqueness *across* different attributes. You can make `cn` unique, which would be very unusual, and you should certainly make `mail` unique, but there is no connection between them. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP When I try to set an email to a user I have this message : `Attribute value would not be unique
This update has been or will be cancelled, it would result in an attribute value not being unique. You might like to search the LDAP server for the offending entry.`

Comment: When you set the `mail` attribute? That can only mean that another entry already has the same value in its `mail` attribute. Nothing to do with `cn` whatsoever. Can you post the configuration of your `unique` overlay?

Comment: How do I do that ? I don't have any `slapd.conf`. I modify my server configuration using ldap utils:  **ldapmodify / ldapadd / ldapdelete**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `cn` whatsoever.

It is because you have your `unique` overlay misconfigured, or not well enough configured. You may be using the legacy `unique_attributes` entry, or you may only have one `unique_uri` entry.

You should use *multiple* [unique_uri](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-unique) entries to define that the `mail` attribute must be unique under `dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=com` and again, separately, under `ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com`, and maybe again under `dc=mailAlias,...`, whatever you need.

**EDIT** Something like:

```
unique_uri=ldap:///dc=mailAccount,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=com?mail?sub ldap:///ou=users,ou=school,o=vdm,dc=domain,dc=com?mail?sub
```

and maybe

```
ldap:///dc=mailAlias,dc=domain.com,dc=mail,dc=domain,dc=com?mail?sub
```

or of course `olcUniqueURI:` instead of `unique_uri=` if you're using online configuration, which you should.

And don't forget to remove the old `unique_attributes` or `olcUniqueAttributes` entry. Note what it is in case there are other attributes being made unique, in which case you will have to configure them in `olcUniqueURI` as well. For example I also have `uid` and `displayName` as unique. And as I don't want to scope those, that means:

```
olcUniqueURI: ldap:///?mail,uid,displayName?sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the link and for pointing me in the right direction. The documentation is very short do you have a more concrete example to get started ?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my tree. I use this [image](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap#edit-your-server-configuration) of openldap and I think I am using online configuration. I have a set of ldif file that init my server. (See [example 1](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap/blob/stable/example/extend-osixia-openldap/bootstrap/ldif/billy.ldif)) I am not sure in which dn I should append `olcUniqueURI`. is it `olcSchemaConfig` ?

Comment: In  my case it is `olcOverlay={1}unique.ldif` under `slapd.d`. Your mileage will vary. But you should not modify this file directly: you should create an LDIF file for the modification, and omit all `{n}` numbers, then use `ldapmodify`.

Comment: I am still trying to test some configurations and I get pain to read/write the configuration. (I have just used my entities ldif files) I am using phpldapadmin so I can only import ldif files. This is the only access I have and I assume it use ldap modify. Do you know how to read and edit theses configuration field ?

Answer (score 0):

You could configure a map like `/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf` with something like this :

```
server_host = ldap.example.com
search_base = ou=users,ou=developers,o=orga,dc=domain,dc=com

# look for entries with this
query_filter = (|(uid=%s)(mailacceptinggeneralid=%s)(mail=%s@domain.com))

# what attribute from the search result is returned
result_attribute = mail

# the format in which the result is returned
result_format = %s
```

With this kind of configuration you should not need a specfic branch to configure email accounts.

Comment: I am confused, I am using `ldap-accounts.cf` for configuring the users accounts and `ldap-aliases.cf` for creating mail alias. I have updated my post with my ldap configuration

Comment: @BigDong Can you edit your question with an export of the LDAP data? I can't understand what is your problem anymore

Comment: I have updated with the LDAP data. Can you look at the mail attribute?